# text channel perms in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I change the channel permissions to specific roles in discord.py?

I've got this:

```
@commands.command()
async def change_perms(self, ctx, role):
    ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.role, send_messages=true)
```

but it no work

Comment: @NikkieDev has provided the correct answer. One thing I wanted to mention was that `true` is not a python keyword, however `True` is a keyword. Please make the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're doing a few things wrong.

Use TextChannel.set_permissions:

```
@commands.command()
async def change_perms(self, ctx):

    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)
```

That might work :)